# Question about symmetric matrices and similarity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials, similar-matrices

Let, two symmetric real $n \times n$ matrices have the same minimal polynomial, are they similar?

I know that they are congruent, but are they also similar? If it's false, what is a counterexample?

Comment: What do you know about the diagonalizability of symmetric real matrices? What does that tell you about their minimal polynomials?

Comment: @amd I know that for a real symmetric matrix $A$, it's true that $C^{-1} A C$ is diagonal where $C \in O(n)$. But, I'm not sure how to relate all of that to minimal polynomials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Diag(0,0,1)$ and $Diag(0,1,1)$ have the same minimal polynomial $X^2-X=0$, but not similar since they have different rank.